# HTML from an API to React-Native

Tags: json, react-native, api, webview

I am getting an API call that has HTML tags! The tags are showing when I parse the JSON file in the app. When I use `Text` tags the data shows with the HTML tags

```
<WebView 
  style={TermsStyles.Text}> 
source = {
   this.state.dataSource
} 
</WebView>
```

When I try and render the API call with `WebView` tags, I get an error of

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to use WebView instead of HTML Renderer from this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html)

When you are ready to call your `API` you will need to call it like this.

```
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <HTML source={{ html: this.state.dataSource }} />
    </ScrollView>
```